# Why has the higher low function highlighted the wrong candles?

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5

The code is supposed to look at a certain previous pivot such as 'tplF' and check wether the current low is higher then the 'tplF' value. I derived it from the Divergence Indicator from TradingView. I have multiple sizes of pivots to compare and if the low is higher than the last pivot low then the RSI is highlighted red, however the RSI is highlighting red at times where I cannot find a reason.
P.S This is supposed to find hidden divergences

```
rangeHigh = 300
rangeLow = 5

tinyLow = ta.pivotlow(5,5)
midLow = ta.pivotlow(10,10)
bigLow = ta.pivotlow(20,20)
massiveLow = ta.pivotlow(40,40)

tinyHigh = ta.pivothigh(5,5)
midHigh = ta.pivothigh(10,10)
bigHigh = ta.pivothigh(20,20)
massiveHigh = ta.pivothigh(40,40)

RSItinyLow = ta.pivotlow(RSI,5,5)
RSImidLow = ta.pivotlow(RSI,10,10)
RSIbigLow = ta.pivotlow(RSI,20,20)
RSImassiveLow = ta.pivotlow(RSI,40,40)

RSItinyHigh = ta.pivothigh(RSI,5,5)
RSImidHigh = ta.pivothigh(RSI,10,10)
RSIbigHigh = ta.pivothigh(RSI,20,20)
RSImassiveHigh = ta.pivothigh(RSI,40,40)


//Finding Pivots RSI

tplF = na(RSItinyLow) ? false : true
mplF = na(RSImidLow) ? false : true
bplF = na(RSIbigLow) ? false : true
maplF = na(RSImassiveLow) ? false : true

tphF = na(RSItinyHigh) ? false : true
mphF = na(RSImidHigh) ? false : true
bphF = na(RSIbigHigh) ? false : true
maphF = na(RSImassiveHigh) ? false : true

//Finding Pivots Price

tplFP = na(tinyLow) ? false : true
mplFP = na(midLow) ? false : true
bplFP = na(bigLow) ? false : true
maplFP = na(massiveLow) ? false : true

tphFP = na(tinyHigh) ? false : true
mphFP = na(midHigh) ? false : true
bphFP = na(bigHigh) ? false : true
maphFP = na(massiveHigh) ? false : true

_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLow  <= bars and bars <= rangeHigh

//Bullish Divergence
//RSI lower low

rsiTLL = ta.lowest(RSI, 5) < ta.valuewhen(tplF,RSI[1],1) and _inRange(tplF[1])

rsiMLL = ta.lowest(RSI, 5) < ta.valuewhen(mplF,RSI[1],1) and _inRange(mplF[1])
rsiMLL2 = ta.lowest(RSI, 5) < ta.valuewhen(mplF,RSI[2],2) and _inRange(mplF[2])

rsiBLL = ta.lowest(RSI, 5) < ta.valuewhen(bplF,RSI[1],1) and _inRange(bplF[1])
rsiBLL2 = ta.lowest(RSI, 5) < ta.valuewhen(bplF,RSI[2],2) and _inRange(bplF[2])

rsiMALL = ta.lowest(RSI, 5) < ta.valuewhen(maplF,RSI[1],1) and _inRange(maplF[1])
rsiMALL2 = ta.lowest(RSI, 5) < ta.valuewhen(maplF,RSI[2],2) and _inRange(maplF[2])

//Price higher low

priceTHL = ta.lowest(low, 5) > ta.valuewhen(tplFP,low[1],1) and _inRange(tplFP[1])

priceMHL = ta.lowest(low, 5) > ta.valuewhen(mplFP,low[1],1) and _inRange(tplFP[1])
priceMHL2 = ta.lowest(low, 5) > ta.valuewhen(mplFP,low[2],2) and _inRange(mplFP[2])

priceBHL = ta.lowest(low, 5) > ta.valuewhen(bplFP,low[1],1) and _inRange(bplFP[1])
priceBHL2 = ta.lowest(low, 5) > ta.valuewhen(bplFP,low[2],2) and _inRange(bplFP[2])

priceMAHL = ta.lowest(low, 5) > ta.valuewhen(maplFP,low[1],1) and                                        _inRange(maplFP[1])


//Defining Bull Divergence

hiddenBulltiny1 = rsiTLL and priceTHL

hiddenBullmid1 =  rsiMLL and priceMHL
hiddenBullmid2 =  rsiMLL2 and priceMHL2

hiddenBullbig1 = rsiBLL and priceBHL
hiddenBullbig2 = rsiBLL2 and priceBHL2

hiddenBullmassive1 = rsiMALL and priceMAHL

BullishHiddenDivergence = hiddenBulltiny1 or hiddenBullmid1 or hiddenBullmid2 or        hiddenBullbig1 or hiddenBullbig2 or hiddenBullmassive1
rsiColor = color.white
if BullishHiddenDivergence
    rsiColor := color.red
plot(RSI,color=rsiColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Means BullishHiddenDivergence is true for some candles and then rsiColor is set to color.red

Comment: If you try putting it in trading view you will see that the RSI turns red at wierd times